# WebShare API not sharing images on iOS: Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am using the WebShare API to share images natively to different apps via Web. It is working perfectly fine on Android devices and they are sharing the images and the text. However, the same API on Safari in iOS is unable to do so. It is sharing only the text that goes along with the image but the image itself is missing.

This is my code in angular:

```js
share() {
    if (this.windowNavigator.share) {
      this.windowNavigator
        .share({
          files: [this.file],
          title: "Title of the image",
          text: "Text to accompany the image",
        })
        .then(() => console.log("Share was successful."))
        .catch((error) => console.log("Sharing failed", error));
    } else {
      console.error("Cannot use Web Share API");
    }
  }
```

Kindly help me proceed

Answer (score 0):

File sharing on iOS via the WebShare API is not supported. It is supported only on Android.